# OSX 10.6 (& Qt): check bitness of running process - even if in 32bit-compatibility mode

Tags: macos, qt, process, 64-bit, 32-bit

How can I check inside the running process for the own bitness-state: that means if "Intel" (32 bit) or "Intel (64-Bit)" because I want to set a certain limit depending on that result.
The problem is that it doesn't help to check during  compile-time since you can set by using `Finder > Information` the compatibility mode to 32 bit.

Is there (inside Qt) something like the `IsWow64Process-command` for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know the machine hardware instead of the current process architecture your code is running.

Shell command `uname -m` will return the name of the underlying hardware. On a 64-bit machine it will return the strig 'x86_64'.

Use [`QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) to invoke the command and check the returned data.

Comment: Not helpful, since I won't check for the hardware. The "bitness" of the running process is the question. /procinfo isn't available for OSX :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a compiler-defined preprocessor macro `__LP64__` that will be true in 64-bit code.  This is a compile-time check, but that's OK.  The only way you'd be able to use the Finder to set 32 bit mode on or off is if you have compiled code for both architectures.

Comment: Yeah, there is code for both modes inside the app. The solution is to check for Q_WS_MAC32 defined? Else Q_WS_MAC64 is usable. Looks like "32 bit mode" is not done by emulating something but by selecting just the 32 bit-binaries inside the app. Therefore everything is easier than expected.